# Walking on water

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, weight, fluid-statics

I was wondering about walking on water. I wonder if we can use surface tension to do this.
Lets say I make a pair of shoes in shape which has infinite perimeter (e.g a koch snowflake) with glass.
Now let's say I step on the surface of distilled water. Since distilled water and glass have a contact angle of $0$, the force of surface tension should be maximum.
The force I experience due to surface tension is given by
$F=TL$ 
Where $T$ is the surface tension of water and $L$ is the perimeter.
It can be observed that if $L=\infty$ the force will also be infinity.
I am aware that it isn't practically possible to make a perfect koch snowflake, but should a well made koch snowflake be able to lift a man of $80\text{kg}$ i.e $784\text{N}$ practically? If yes, then why aren't we walking on water?!!

Comment: Since the force is based on the wetted perimeter, any configuration that would make the perimeter very large in a very small area would be overwhelmed by the surface tension of the water droplets connecting nearby perimeters.  So the effective perimeter would be much lower.  So you are sunk!

Comment: It's fundamentally impossible to even come close to making a Koch snowflake. At some point, the length of a side is less than the size of an atom. You stop there. Furthermore, water will see this and treat it like a rounded edge. Using surface tension will not work for humans. Buoyancy will work, but you'd have essentially no traction

Answer (score 3):

Since the force is based on the wetted perimeter, any configuration that would make the perimeter very large in a very small area would be overwhelmed by the surface tension of the water droplets connecting nearby perimeters. So the effective perimeter would be much lower. So you are sunk!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your simplistic assumption that the perimeter is the only thing that matters. The actual force can be no greater that the weight of displaced water (see for example a capillary) and as the force you try to exert, so the amount of water displaced will increase.

That doesn't mean you could not use surface tension to "walk on water" - just that when you have made the right kind of "shoe", it will sink into the water in inverse proportion with its area. Which makes it no different from some "water skis" that exist today which allow you to "shuffle" on water (imaging one hull of a small catamaran strapped to each foot and you get the idea).

Answer (score 1):

Your fractal pattern will fail for reasons already given.  However, given a large enough lake, you should be able to stand on a frame which is supported by a very long (perhaps circular) wire.  All you need is for the force per meter (assuming uniformly applied) caused by your body weight and the structure itself to be less than the surface tension force constant of water.   Note that this constant depends on the  material you use for the  wire.